# Hello world example for Apollo Client 2 + React?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

Im trying to return a string with React and GraphQL but I'm getting stuck at the first stage. Here is my attempt:

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';

const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    author: Person
  }
  type Person {
    name: String
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        author: { name: 'billy' },
    },
};

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
});

createApolloServer({ schema });
```

And this is my understanding of that code:

In my schema I've defined a `Query` called `author` which should return a `Person`.

A `Person` has a name field which is a string.

My resolver has a `Query` called `author` which should return an object with a name field of value 'billy'

However in my Graphicool browser tools this query:

```
query {
  author{
     name
  }
}
```

Returns this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "author": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvers are functions which GraphQL will call when resolving that particular field. That means your `resolvers` object should look more like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    author: () => ({ name: 'billy' }),
  },
}
```

Or, alternatively,

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    author() {
      return { name: 'billy' }
    },
  },
}
```

You can [check out the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createApolloServer } from 'meteor/apollo';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import merge from 'lodash/merge'; // will be useful later when their are more schemas 

import GroupsSchema from './Groups.graphql';
import GroupsResolvers from './resolvers';

const typeDefs = [GroupsSchema];
const resolvers = merge(GroupsResolvers);

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
});

createApolloServer({ schema });
```

In ./Groups.graphql:

```
type Query {
    hi: String
    groups: [Group]
    group: Group
}

type Group {
    name: String
}
```

In './resolvers':

```
export default {
    Query: {
        hi() {
            return 'howdy';
        },
        groups() {
            return [{ name: 'one', _id: '123' }, { name: 'two', _id: '456' }];
            // return Groups.find().fetch();
        },
        group() {
            return { name: 'found me' };
        },
    },
};
```

In a React component:

```
const mainQuery = gql`
    {
        groups {
            name
        }
    }
`;

export default graphql(mainQuery)(ComponentName);
```